# How to get first item of FIrebase Database Result in Python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm using `Firebase Admin SDK` for `Python` to get data from Realtime Database but all of the examples seem to use for loops to iterate the data rather.

```
from firebase_admin import db
ref = db.reference('users')
results = ref.order_by_child('name').equal_to(uniqueID).limit_to_first(1).get()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The the type returned by `.get()` seems to always be a `OrderedDict` even when `limit_to_first(1)` is used to only get `1` result. Use `.popitem()` to get the first element without using a `for` loop.

```
from firebase_admin import db
ref = db.reference('users')
results = ref.order_by_child('name').equal_to(uniqueID).limit_to_first(1).get()
firstItem = results.popitem()
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jim's answer is not wrong but `popitem()` will remove the item from the `results` dictionary. If you want to get the first item, you can use do this:

```
firstKey = next(iter(results.keys())) # Python 3.x
firstKey = results.iterkeys().next()  # Python 2.x
```

that will return the key for the first item. And you can get the value using the `firstKey` like this

```
value = results[firstKey]
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since your `results` can have at most 1 item, following will also run pretty efficiently:

```
if results:
    key, val = results.items()[0]
```